# Collision detection problems

Tags: collision-detection, cocos2d-x

I was totally new in **cocos2d-x**. 
Just start from developing a simple game which is like **"The Plane War"**

A problems confuse me when I implement the collision detection.

- Assuming that **The player's plane** can fire **50+ bullet** every
  time.
- More than **50+ enemies** appear on the screen.

That means I have to do **50 * 50** times detection every frame, **2500** times!
The game's performance should be fall ...

So how can I optimise the collision detection?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak as to Cocos2d as I don't use it. But the general solutions include:

**Break your game world down into regions**

E.g. divide your world into 100x100 pixel blocks. At the start of every frame for each object work out which blocks (note the plural) it overlaps. That should be cheap if you've divided your world regularly. Add your object to a list of objects in every block.

Following that, run through your objects again and this time read from the blocks. Test against all other objects that overlap any other block your object overlaps.

More complicated division strategies might include a quad tree or kd-tree. If your world is already inherently divided (e.g. into convex sectors for certain kinds of speedy collision or visibility calculations) then you can often piggyback off that.

**Iterate along a sorted list**

Pick any dimension your world is longest along. Let's say it is wider than tall for argument's sake, and you don't want to bother thinking about diagonals.

Then sort all your objects by starting x position.

Now iterate along the list. For each the object at position `i` in the list, check it against those at `i+1`, `i+2`, etc until you get to the very first object for which its leftmost x is beyond your rightmost. Then stop considering the object at `i` and allow the loop to roll on to the next object. The object you're considering definitely can't collide with anything beyond the object you stopped checking at because they all have leftmost edges even further to the right.

This is one of the rare occasions when insertion sort can be the fastest sort because it's optimal — O(n) — if applied to a list that is already sorted and generally closer to optimal the closer the list is to sorted. In a game your object orderings are likely to change only a little between frames so if they were sorted last frame they're quite likely to be close to sorted this frame.

**Don't then jump straight to the expensive test**

Those are both broad-phase detection strategies that prevent comparisons between objects that definitely don't overlap. Even once you're down to object versus object you should consider doing some broad-phase stuff before doing an exact pixel check. The easiest solution is bounding spheres — work out a centre and a radius for each object then as a first check work out the square of the distance between the two centres (using Pythagoras but not moving beyond the square of the distance to avoid that costly square root) and compare it to the square of the sum of the two radii. If the two objects aren't at least that close then they can't overlap so you can skip the more exact stuff.

Depending on your costs and the general shapes of your geometry you might also consider convex hulls and separating axes (especially if you have a sufficiently fast mechanism to cache which axis separated any two given objects last time).

Comment: Thank you @Tommy ~ That's a good idea to solve my problems through the pixel block. Actually I have another idea that is use the **multithreading**, I am not sure if that can improve the performance.It seems that I still have to do **2500 times** detection...... What do you think?

Comment: 2,500 times is the best case (assuming you count any test as a collision detection; a lot of those tests will be a lot cheaper than a full-on test) — it should be between 2,500 and the worst case of (2500*2500)/2 = 3,125,000 and usually a lot closer to 2,500. But once you're iterating the final list you might consider batching it into groups of, say, 100 or 500 or whatever suggests itself during profiling and using `dispatch_apply` to get GCD to schedule it between cores. There's a cost to the scheduling, hence the need to profile and pick a decent batch size.